# Precise overloaded function calls in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, overloading

I'm new to TypeScript and trying to use it with AngularJS. Here's a situation that's bothering me because I can't get an error from the compiler.

In Angular (AFAIK), a resource provider has a `get()` method that returns an instance of `T`, `T` being a type parameter. This method has many other overloads, and can accept `params` or `data` parameters, and possibly a success and an error handler with signatures like this:

```
interface IResourceSuccessCallbackFunction<T> {
    (value: T, responseHeaders: Array<string>): void;
}

interface IResourceErrorCallbackFunction {
    (httpResponse: string): void;
}
```

I took inspiration from the **[corresponding declaration file at DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular-resource.d.ts)** to come up with these overloads for the `get` function:

```
interface IResourceClass<T> {
    get(): T;
    get(dataOrParams: any): T;
    get(dataOrParams: any, success: IResourceSuccessCallbackFunction<T>): T;
    get(success: IResourceSuccessCallbackFunction<T>, error?: IResourceErrorCallbackFunction): T;
    get(params: any, data: any, success?: IResourceSuccessCallbackFunction<T>, error?: IResourceErrorCallbackFunction): T;
}
```

My problem is that those definitions allow me to write stuff like this:

```
var resourceService: IResourceClass<number> = null;
var res1 = resourceService.get({ id: 1000 }, function() {
    console.log("fail");
});
var res2 = resourceService.get(function(p: Phone) {
    console.log(p);
}, function() {
    console.log("fail");
});
```

Obviously, here, for `res1`, the programmer made a mistake by passing an error handler as second argument, forgetting about the success handler; and for `res2`, the supposed success handler is accepting the wrong type `Phone` instead of `number`.

Now, I know why those two calls compile and are valid: the last overloaded version is always a match, because it allows two `any` params and two optional params, which are here absent. So I'm looking for a way to define the overloaded variants that would catch those errors. For instance, replace `any` with a type that would say “not a function”, or though some other trick.

Is this possible?

Comment: You're wanting to catch those errors at compile time, right? You're definitely right, the `any` is too permissive.

Comment: Yes, I’d like to get those errors at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, remove the overloads with `any`. I'm not sure if that's applicable in this case; it depends on how the API works.

`res1` will always be OK because you're not *required* to consume parameters in TypeScript (imagine how annoying it would be if you had to have a three-parameter callback to Array#forEach).

For `res2`, you can sometimes improve the situation by adding "trap" overloads:

```
interface IResourceClass<T> {
    get(): T;
    get(success: IResourceSuccessCallbackFunction<T>, error?: IResourceErrorCallbackFunction): T;
    get(otherFunction1: (...a: any[]) => void, otherFunction2: (...a: any[]) => void): { YOU_HAVE_FAILED: {}; };
    get(dataOrParams: any): T;
    get(dataOrParams: any, success: IResourceSuccessCallbackFunction<T>): T;
    get(params: any, data: any, success?: IResourceSuccessCallbackFunction<T>, error?: IResourceErrorCallbackFunction): T;
}

var resourceService: IResourceClass<number> = null;
var res1 = resourceService.get({ id: 1000 }, function() {
    console.log("fail");
});
// res2: { YOU_HAVE_FAILED: {} }
var res2 = resourceService.get(function(p: Phone) {
    console.log(p);
}, function() {
    console.log("fail");
});
```

This won't be a compile error immediately, but any practical use of `res2` will be an error.

Comment: Thanks. The “trap” overload idea is interesting. How about defining, e.g., `interface Nothing {}` and returning `Nothing` instead? Would it be a bad idea? BTW, the overload resolution tests the different signatures strictly in declaration order, right?

Comment: Yes, signatures are tested strictly in order. The problem with `Nothing` is that you can assign anything *to* it; having a FAIL member prevents that.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help. Any chance the language would some day include such an “error” type — or lets us somehow more formally specify invalid function signature in a similar way?

Comment: One more question: does `(...a: any[]) => void` match every function, and thus acts as a function type wildcard?